# Wordpress — Replace TinyMCE with TEXTAREA?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I'm using Wordpress with TinyMCE.

What a piece of junk TinyMCE is!

TinyMCE reformats my HTML, including by removing all of the `p` tags. I've even chosen the wordpress option to have it to not do that. Doesn't work.

Sometimes, TinyMCE doubles sections of content or completely changes the HTML source to be totally broken.

How can I replace TinyMCE with TEXTAREA? I just want to type my HTML code in and not have it be damaged by the plugin.

Comment: Are you using it on a custom post type?

Comment: no. . . . . . . .